# VirtualBox Flask Server / Ubuntu 16.04 32-bit / Server stops responding periodically

Tags: python, flask, virtualbox, ubuntu-16.04, gunicorn

I'm not sure where to post this since I don't really know if this is an issue with Flask, VirtualBox (6.0) or Ubuntu (16.04 LTS).

**Intro**

My company installs Ubuntu VMs for our clients that run a local Flask web server on their system. I know Flask is not meant to be used for production, but each individual server handles about 15 users max (and often just 1 or 2) and usually only one or two users at a time. So far it's been working well for dozens of clients over several months.

**Problem**

We have a couple of clients where the application becomes inaccessible in users' browsers after a certain period of time. I can SSH to the VM and see that the Flask service still seems to be running without issue. But the users are not able to connect to the IP address and port of the VM via their browser like they could before (eg. *http://<vm_ip>:<port_number>*).

Restarting the service doesn't resolve the issue, but restarting the entire VM does resolve it.

The flask application runs as a service, but all the service is doing is triggering a bash script that runs `python run.py`.

The VM network adapter is set to "NAT" and it serves the Flask app on the same IP address as the host machine. When the app becomes inaccessible, I'm not able to connect to the application on the host machine using either *http://<vm_ip>:<port_number>* or *http://localhost:<port_number>*. We have this same configuration on many client systems and it works without issue for all other clients.

Nothing should change in the application configuration when the VM restarts. All networking and port settings are static. So something is clearly getting hung up. Since the application output doesn't show anything off and the Flask service seems to restart fine internally, I'm guessing the issue is with Ubuntu or VirtualBox (or something on the client machine/network).

**Question**

I'm wondering what would cause a Flask server that runs very reliably in most cases, to periodically stop responding after a certain amount of time, even though the VM is accessible and Flask appears to be running fine internally.

I apologize for lack of details and logs - our access to the client machine is limited. I will try to get my hands on these.

Comment: What do you mean by "inaccessible"?

Comment: Thanks - I was a little low on details there. I've added some more info, let me know if anything else is unclear!

Comment: How you're running the flask application ?

Comment: Good question - I've added a brief description. Basically a linux service is triggering a batch file that runs "python run.py".
The host value in app.run() is set to "0.0.0.0" I've seen a lot of similar issues where that was the solution. But our application is already working in most cases so I think our method for running the application is not the problem here

Comment: You're just running one process? Are you not using something like Gunicorn or uWSGI?

Comment: We're only running one process at the moment. We're currently working out an implementation with NGINX that will handle HTTPS and we'll be looking into multiple worker processes with that